# Generating Random Numbers Within a Specified Range Using Crypto++

Tags: c++, random, crypto++

How do you generate random numbers within a specified range using the crypto++ AutoSeededRandomPool random number generator.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you generate random numbers within a specified range ...

Use an `Integer`, which is multi-precision. The contructor of interest:

```
Integer (RandomNumberGenerator &rng, const Integer &min, const Integer &max,
         RandomNumberType rnType=ANY, const Integer &equiv=Zero(), const Integer &mod=One())
```

See [Integer Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html) for details.

---

> ... using the crypto++ `AutoSeededRandomPool`

`AutoSeededRandomPool` is derived from `RandomNumberGenerator`, so you will be able to use it.

See [AutoSeededRandomPool Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_auto_seeded_random_pool.html) for details.